# get value at lowest index in a array from the values of another array with javascript programming

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 set of array

```
var A = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"];
var B = ["B", "J", "A", "C", "G"];
```

now I have to a value from var `B` which is at highest & lowest index in var `A`, it is `J` & `A`

I have to find out `J` & `A` in var `B` by JavaScript programming

here is my code working ok with above example var `A` & `B` but work with my actual requirement

```
var C = ["SX", "S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL", "ML", "LL", "XLL", "MK", "LK", "XLK", "MS", "LS", "XLS"];
 var D = ["XLL", "XXL", "XLK"];
```

```js
var A = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"];
var B = ["B", "J", "A", "C", "G"];
  
 var C = ["SX", "S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL", "ML", "LL", "XLL", "MK", "LK", "XLK", "MS", "LS", "XLS"];
 var D = ["XLL", "XXL", "XLK"];

function customArrayFunction(A, B) {
  var sortB = [];
  B.forEach(v => sortB.push(v));
  var res = B.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a < b)
      return -1;
    else if (a > b)
      return 1;
    return 0;
  }).find(v => A.indexOf(v) > -1);

  return res;
}
document.write(customArrayFunction(A, B));
document.write('<br>' + customArrayFunction(C, D));
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you explain more i didnt understand what are u trying to do ?

Comment: @John basically I need to find a lowest index value in var C with reference of var d, eg in var D  "XXL" is value which is at lowest index in var C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a proposal with a temporary `object` for the indices of the given array `ordered` and some comparisons if the sort index is smaller or bigger than the actual value for return.

```js
function x(ordered, search) {
    var object = {},
        result;
    ordered.forEach(function (k, i) {
        object[k] = i;
    });
    search.forEach(function (a) {
        if (!result) {
            result = [a, a];
            return;
        }
        if (object[a] < object[result[0]]) {
            result[0] = a;
            return;
        }
        if (object[a] > object[result[1]]) {
            result[1] = a;
        }
    });
    return result;
}

var a = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"],
    b = ["B", "J", "A", "C", "G"],
    c = ["SX", "S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL", "ML", "LL", "XLL", "MK", "LK", "XLK", "MS", "LS", "XLS"],
    d = ["XLL", "XXL", "XLK"];

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(x(a, b), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(x(c, d), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: thanks, can you let me know what's use of 0, 4

Comment: @Dinesh, it's part of [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), the replacer and space parameter. replacer is not given, hence `0` and space is `4` for indent.